# How to build App without App.runtimeconfig.json?

Tags: .net-core, configuration-files

When I build the `App` in `Release` mode in Visual Studio it generates these files in Release folder:

```
App.exe 
App.dll 
App.runtimeconfig.json 
App.pdb
App.deps.json
App.runtimeconfig.dev.json
```

If I move the first 3 files location and double click the `App.exe` it starts. If I delete `App.runtimeconfig.json` it doesn't start!

I want to keep only `App.exe` and `App.dll` in my folder, what do I have to do to get rid of that `App.runtimeconfig.json`?

---

**EDIT #1**

Here's the content of `App.runtimeconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp3.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App",
      "version": "3.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT #2**

Here's what I've now in my `App.csproj` file's `PropertyGroup`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

now I get this in `Error List` of Visual studio:

> Error NETSDK1047  Assets file 'C:\Users\Emon\source\repos\SocketTest\App\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0/win-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. App C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    234

When I right click on Project I see: Build, Clean, Rebuild, etc., there's no restore!

---

**EDIT #3**

I've deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders first and reordered the `<PropertyGroup>` to put the `<RuntimeIdentifier>` beneath the `<TargetFramework>`, now it works!

Comment: What is the content of file? It contains runtime information and used .NET core version. You try to switch to self contained deployment

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, edited my post and added the content. How to deploy as `self contained` in visual studio? If you don't mind post the process in answer section please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see, `App.runtimeconfig.json` contains the runtime information and used .NET Core version, you can't simply delete it. But you switch to self contained deployment by selecting `Self-contained` deployment mode when publish the app

.NET Core introduced the ability to trim the result executable to reduce size. Basically, you need the following properties in your project file

```
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

There is a very nice [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx) about single executables

Comment: But `RuntimeIdentifier` is here:) Please, ensure that you are using it correctly and not using the `RuntimeIdentifiers` in plural form

Comment: Yes I missed that last time, But this time I've included that line and now I get another error. I've updated the post to show What I've done in csproj and  the error

Comment: Look at this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1321)

Comment: Yes, now it works, I just have to have all the required `dll` and `exe`, nothing else.

Comment: For my reference, If I want a single `exe`, without any `.dll`, I've to click on `Publish` instead of `Build`, great!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to keep my csproj file as generic as possible and didn't want to specify any `RuntimeIdentifiers` in that file.  I would rather specify the `RuntimeIdentifier` as a command line build option.  This is what I came up with:

csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>false</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
        <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
        <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
        <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Command line:

```
dotnet publish --runtime win-x64 -c Release
```